# how get groups last column element

Tags: css-selectors, pyquery

How use css selector find the last element in same elements each line on python? I'm using package pyquery.

I has tried `tr td:nth-child(2) .score.fill:last-child`, `tr td:nth-child(2) .score.fill:nth-last-child(1)`. all failed.

```html
<table>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Vote A</td>
            <td>
                <span class="score fill">1</span>
                <span class="score">2</span>
                <span class="score">3</span>
                <span class="score">4</span>
                <span class="score">5</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vote B</td>
            <td>
                <span class="score fill">1</span>
                <span class="score fill">2</span>
                <span class="score fill">3</span>
                <span class="score fill">4</span>
                <span class="score fill">5</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Vote C</td>
            <td>
                <span class="score fill">1</span>
                <span class="score fill">2</span>
                <span class="score fill">3</span>
                <span class="score">4</span>
                <span class="score">5</span>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I want get result like this:

```html
<span class="score fill">1</span>
<span class="score fill">5</span>
<span class="score fill">3</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

this won't work, because of .score.fill:last-child this selector means element with classes score and fill AND also last child.

You can select this with only CSS, you have to located this by JS and for examle add one more class for them.

This is feature which will be in new css :nth selectors [here is link](https://drafts.csswg.org/selectors/#the-nth-child-pseudo)

[Here is something can help](https://dev.to/brightdevs/simulating-nth-of-class-css-selector-pg)